# How to convert CLLocationCoordinate2D latitude and longtitute to double?

Tags: google-maps, swift3, cllocation

How to convert `CLLocationCoordinate2D` latitude and longtitute to `Double` in Swift 3?

Comment: No need to convert coordinate.latitude & longtitute to double value. latitude & longtitude already in double value only. you will assign by a variable like let lati = coordinate.latitude, ..

Answer (score 2):

The [`latitude`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d/1423513-latitude) and [`longitude`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d/1423552-longitude) instance properities of [CLLocationCoordinate2D](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d) are of type [`CLLocationDegrees`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationdegrees), which is a `typealias` for `Double`.

So you really don't need to do anything:

```
func printDouble(_ d: Double) { print(d) }

let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 123.0, longitude: 456.0)
printDouble(coords.latitude) // Works just fine
printDouble(coords.longitude)
```